# Why does Giraffe/AspNetCore + SignalR dependency injection fail to resolve a MailboxProcessor singleton?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, f#, f#-giraffe

I'm setting up a simple [Giraffe](https://github.com/giraffe-fsharp/Giraffe) app with one or two endpoints and a SignalR hub.  What I have is like this:

```
type JsonBlob = JsonProvider<"Blob.json">
type Message = 
    | GetBlobs of AsyncReplyChannel<JsonBlob.Root list>
    | PostBlob of JsonBlob.Root

type JsonBlobHub(agent : MailboxProcessor<Message>) =
    inherit Hub()
    member self.RespondToClient() =
        let blobs = agent.PostAndReply(GetBlobs)
        self.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveBlobList", blobs)

let agentFactory(serviceProvider : IServiceProvider) =
    let thing = serviceProvider.GetService<Thing>()
    MailboxProcessor.Start(fun (inbox : MailboxProcessor<Message>) ->
        /* loop implementation */
    )

// other stuff
let configureApp (app : IApplicationBuilder) =
    app.UseSignalR(fun routes -> routes.MapHub<JsonBlobHub>(PathString "/blobhub")) |> ignore
    app.UseGiraffe webApp // webApp defined elsewhere, not important

let configureServices (services : IServiceCollection) =
    services.AddSingleton<MailboxProcessor<Message>>(agentFactory) |> ignore
    services.AddGiraffe() |> ignore
    services.AddSignalR() |> ignore

let main argv =
    WebHostBuilder() =
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseWebRoot("WebRoot")
        .Configure(Action<IApplicationBuilder> configureApp)
        .ConfigureServices(configureServices)
        .ConfigureLogging(configureLogging)
        .Build()
        .Run
    0
```

When the SignalR client connects to `/blobhub`, the connection is closed unexpectedly because the app fails to resolve `MailboxProcessor<Message>` while trying to activate the `BlobHub` class.

I'm a bit stumped, however, because I've clearly registered the `MailboxProcessor<Message>` type in the container in the `configureServices` function.  Does anyone see a problem in this code?  Or maybe I'm assuming that these things should work, and there's some reason that they shouldn't that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Not too familar with SignalR and how it does DI, but do you need to register the `JsonBlobHub` class with ASP.NET's DI container so that it will know about JsonBlobHub's constructor parameters?

Comment: I don't _think_ so, because the error message does indicate the correct class as the type it's trying to resolve.  i.e., "Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Control.FSharpMailboxProcessor`1[MyModule+Message]' while attempting to activate 'MyModule+JsonBlobHub`".  This makes me wonder if there's some issue with using a DU type as the type parameter to `MailboxProcessor`, but I'm not super-sure how to prove it

Comment: Hmmm. You could try ruling out the DU type parameter issue by creating a `MailboxProcessor<string>` class and testing with that. If `MailboxProcessor<string>` succeeds where `MailboxProcessor<Message>` fails, then your hypothesis about DU type parameters seems likely.

Comment: Ack.  This does appear to be the issue.  `MailboxProcessor<string>` resolves just fine. :sob:

Comment: What happens if you register `Message` with ASP.NET's DI?

Comment: Well....as often winds up being the case, I just made a dumb mistake.  I had my `Message` type defined in two different modules as a result of moving things around, and my factory function and DI registration saw one version, while the Hub saw another version.

DI is pretty smart, but it's not magical ;-)  Once I removed one of the definitions, the system worked just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well....it turns out that I did a stupid thing and accidentally had two definitions of `Message`.  My `JsonBlobHub` was using one definition while `agentFactory` and `configureServices` were using another definition.  Once I removed one of the definitions of `Message` the DI container resolved the activation of `JsonBlobHub` as you would expect.

I would say that this wound up being a waste of time, but it did actually lead to a nice little self-contained example of using F#, Giraffe, ASP.NET Core, and SignalR together, and demonstrating that all the pieces play nicely together.